# Facebook Social Plugin and jQuery Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, youtube, comments

I'm using jQuery to load some content into a lightbox-like div in a web app I'm working on. Using $POST, I'm calling a dynamically populated page that holds a youtube video and a facebook comment plugin.

The first video I load comes with the comments, but each video after that comes by itself, sans-comments. Any quick ideas as to what might be happening?

This is the page I'm loading.

```
<? $video_id = $_POST['video_id']; ?>

<object width="800" height="499"> 
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/<? echo $video_id; ?>?modestbranding=1&amp;version=3&amp;hl=en_US&rel=0"></param> 
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param> 
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param> 
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/<? echo $video_id; ?>?modestbranding=1&amp;version=3&amp;hl=en_US&rel=0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="499" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed> 
</object>


<h5 style="margin:35px 0 8px 0;">Comment on this Video</h2>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=158242874284543";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXX.com/viewvideo.php?video_id=<? echo $video_id; ?>" data-num-posts="12" data-width="800"></div>
```

And this is the call that brings it in (#view_video is the div that holds the lightbox, .video_wrapper is the div that displays the info that is loaded. Each thumbnail is in a div with the videothumb class, whos id is set to the youtube videos unique id):

```
<script>
    //VIEW VIDEO
    $('.videothumb').click(function() {
        $('#view_video').fadeIn('fast');
        this_video_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post( 'viewvideo.php', { video_id: this_video_id },
            function( data ) {
                //on complete
                $('.video_wrapper').html(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you load the first page, the Facebook JS SDK get’s loaded as well, and parses the XFBML tags in your document.

The next time you AJAX-load a page into your document, the JS SDK is already embeded into your document, so nothing further happens – and that includes no new parsing of XFBML tags.

You have to use [`FB.XFBML.parse`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) to tell the SDK that it should again search the document for (dynamically added) XFBML tags. (Preferable give it a DOM node as first parameter, so that it does not search the whole document again, but just the part where dynamic changes have occured.)

Comment: I see. So I need to add that call in after $('.video_wrapper').html(data); ?