# how to load facebook activity feed in website only when called or facebook is selected

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have successfully added facebook activity feed in my site.But now I have a dropdown with functions as facebook, twitter, rss feed and so on.So only when I click facebook from the dropdown activity feed should be loaded in that specific portion.How am I do that.I have included the following.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I tried to append as follows.

```
parents.append('<div class="fb-activity fb_iframe_widget" data-header="true" data-height="300" data-width="300" data-action="like,comment,recommend,share,suggest" data-site="http://www.icimod.org/" data-app-id="118280394918580" fb-xfbml-state="rendered">');
```

but it only shows the above div and no feeds.

Any suggestions/advice are welcome.Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Social Plugin and jQuery Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045721/facebook-social-plugin-and-jquery-issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User $.getScript() to dynamically load the script once facebook option is loaded.

```
$.getScript(url)
            .done(function(){
               parents.find('div.item').append('<div class="description disp hover"><div class="fb-activity fb_iframe_widget" data-header="true" data-height="300" data-width="300" data-action="like,comment,recommend,share,suggest" data-site="http://www.icimod.org/" data-app-id="118280394918580"></div></div>'); 
            });
```

get to know about $.getScript().